# How can I fade in the updated characters from an ng-model input?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css-transitions

My website uses an input  `<input type="text" ng-model="name">` and a header `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`. As it should, updated text appears as the user types in the input. Is it possible to have the individual characters fade in instead of just appear as the user types?

Comment: you can probably utilize https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/directive/ngAnimateSwap I messed around with it a bit..not sure if I am using it correctly https://jsfiddle.net/ojzdxpt1/16/

Answer (score 0):

I think its best you use the NgModelController in your advantage here. With that you can read the users input and control what is outputted in the expression. I'm referring to the $viewValue and $modelValue. With this I assume you can create what you want to achieve...